# What is the meaning of memory references as instruction parameters in NDISASM output?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm disassembling programs with ndisasm. My question is what do the memory references mean, after call instructions and jumps?

Are they relative to the instruction or they count from the beginning of the program? Are they referring to the addresses in the first column of the ndisasm output text?

Comment: They refer to the 1st column for relative jumps. For absolute, the actual address encoded in the instruction is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's referring to the address given at the first column of the output, which is normally also the location of the instruction relative to the start of the file. The program doesn't know where the code will be loaded in memory and so can't generally tell you where in memory the destination actually is.

Note that is only true for the destination addresses of near direct jump and call instructions (including the conditional Jcc jump instructions) as these addresses are encoded relative to the instruction. Addresses in other instructions don't use a relative encoding, so the address displayed doesn't refer to the addresses in the first column. Instead it's the actual address used at runtime, assuming that program isn't relocated somewhere else when loaded into memory.

(64-bit RIP-relative addressing is an exception to the above, instructions using this addressing mode use a relative address encoding.)

Because of these differences in what the displayed addresses actually mean ndisasm is only generally only good at disassembling flat binary files like bootloaders and MS-DOS .COM files. In cases like these you can tell it where the program will be loaded in memory (with the `-o` option) so the addresses displayed are consistent and reflect where the program is loaded in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the help!